# How to store string in stack using array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, stack

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define max 100

int a[max];
int top = -1;
char x;

int isempty() ;
int isfull() ;
void push() ;
int pop() ;
void display() ;

void main()
{
    int ch;

    do
    {

        printf("\n 1. Push");
        printf("\n 2. Pop");
        printf("\n 3. Display");
        printf("\n 4. Exit");
        scanf("%d",&ch);

    switch (ch) {
        case 1:
            push();
            break;
        case 2:
            pop();
            break;
        case 3:
            display();
            break;
        case 4:

            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid Choice");
            break;
        }
    }while(ch!=4)
}

int isfull(){
if ( (top == max-1))
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
}

int isempty(){
if((top==-1))
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
}

void push(){
if (isfull())
{
    printf("Stack is full");
}
else
{
    printf("Enter element to add");
    scanf("%s",x);
    top++;
    strcpy(a[top],x);
    }
}

int pop(){
if(isempty())
{
    printf("Stack is empty");
    exit(0);
}
else{
    strcpy(x,a[top]);
    printf("%s",x);
    top --;
    }
}

void display()
{
if(isempty())
{
    printf("NO data to display");
    exit(0);
}
else
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<top+1;i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n",a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

On running push operation it's exiting with non zero error without performing any action.

We have to add alphanumeric values to the stack by using array and push & pop.
It should accept a string value and store it in stack array when display is selected it should display all the values.

Can someone help me rectifying the error in this code that why it is not assigning or storing any values to string.

Comment: `int ch;  while(ch!=4)` that's accessing local uninitialized variable...

Comment: any change suggested ?

Comment: use `do-while`.

Comment: still same problem persisting.

Comment: Take the compiler's warnings serious.

Comment: No warning showing compiled successfully.

Comment: Then increase the warning level. For GCC pass `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` at least.

Comment: Do not change the code after comments/answers have been given, as this renders them to be ununderstandable. Add updates. I rolled back your last changes though.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[What do I do when someone answers my
question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer provided all the problems the OP has when used the code posted above. The first part of the solution provides the analysis of those errors and how to deal with them. The second part provides the solution the OP wants to achieve. (To store string in the stack).

You were accessing an uninitialized variable and comparing the garbage value of it with `4`. I suggested `do-while`.

```
 do{
    printf("\n 1. Push");
    printf("\n 2. Pop");
    printf("\n 3. Display");
    printf("\n 4. Exit");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
 ....

 }while(ch!=4);
```

The idea is simple enough. We are getting an input in `ch` and the doing all of the work. The comparison is done at the end of all the work So we are working with a determinate value of `ch` always.

Earlier it seems from your question that the garbage value in `ch` was not equal to `4`. that's why it didn't even enter the loop.

You have made every single variable in your program to be global. The real pain in debugging this will be understood when you get a bug for which we have to trace the data mutation. *Don't use global variables like this.*

#### Major error

You can never store a string in a int array.

```
scanf("%s",x); This is wrong.
```

You are inputting character with `%s` specifier. You should use `%c`. Then also, you cant use `strcpy()` to copy it.

Moreover you don't need `strcpy()` you can simply do it using an aissgnment.
You can store `char` in an `int` variable and in an `int` array.

Corrected code would be (`push()` function):

```
if( scanf(" %c",&x) == 1){
   a[++top]=x;
}
```

Same way in `pop()` function you would use

```
x = a[top--];
printf("%c",x);
```

Also in `display()` function you need to change

```
printf("%c \n",a[i]);
```

Again if you are sure that you will work with characters only why not use a `char` array.

Here `char a[100]` will fit perfectly.

***Also these are the list of errors/warning that your program generates(Without using any flags)***

```
main.c: In function ‘main’: main.c:48:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token  }  ^ main.c: In function ‘pop’: main.c:93:12: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     strcpy(x,a[top]);
            ^ In file included from main.c:2:0: /usr/include/string.h:125:14: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’  extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict
__dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^~~~~~ main.c:93:14: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     strcpy(x,a[top]);
              ^ In file included from main.c:2:0: /usr/include/string.h:125:14: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’  extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict
__dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^~~~~~ main.c: In function ‘main’: main.c:114:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input  }  ^
```

With using the flags as alk said the errors and warnings will be even more.

---

In order to store string you need to consider using a 2d char array. That is one way to realize the string.

#### Code

(For illustration purpose. Only the changes are incorporated. The code has minimal/no error checking.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define max 100

char a[max][max];
int top = -1;
char x[max];

int isempty() ;
int isfull() ;
void push() ;
int pop() ;
void display() ;

int main()
{
    int ch;

    do
    {

        printf("\n 1. Push");
        printf("\n 2. Pop");
        printf("\n 3. Display");
        printf("\n 4. Exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&ch);

        switch (ch) {
        case 1:
            push();
            break;
        case 2:
            pop();
            break;
        case 3:
            display();
            break;
        case 4:

            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid Choice");
            break;
        }
    }while(ch!=4);
    return 0;
}

int isfull(){
    if ( (top == max-1))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int isempty(){
    if((top==-1))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void push(){
    if (isfull())
    {
        printf("Stack is full");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter element to add");
        scanf("%s",x);
        top++;
        strcpy(a[top],x);
    }
}

int pop(){
    if(isempty())
    {
        printf("Stack is empty");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        strcpy(x,a[top]);
        printf("%s",x);
        top--;
    }
}

void display()
{
    if(isempty())
    {
        printf("NO data to display");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<top+1;i++)
        {
            printf("%s \n",a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here in this solution we have used two major changes

#### Explanation

making `char x` to `char x[max]` and also changing `a` from `int [max]` to `char a[max][max]`. Doing that now those can store null terminated char arrays. The 2d array of characters is used to realize the stack over here.

Comment: On using do while loop also it's giving same error and performing no operation. Just try once this code in your system you will get the idea.

Comment: Now it's even not asking for input just check out the update.

Comment: @Vivank.: Have you copied it corectly? Because it works for me...have you checked the `'  '` in `scanf`

Comment: @Vivank.: If you don't know how to copy the changes and understand accordingly then that is not my fault. The answer provides everything for the program to work properly